# ServiceStack serialized byte[]. How to deserialize in javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript, byte, servicestack

I am serializing a byte array from C# code

```
byte[] sample = new byte[] {0,0};
```

with ServiceStack (json).
The result value in json is **"AAA="**.

How to deserialize this to get an array with two elements **(0,0)** instead of **"AAA="**?

I am javascript beginner, so please forgive me the question. Maybe ServiceStack is using some kind of encoding i don't know of. If yes, how to decode it correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ServiceStack is serializing the `byte[]` as a Base64 string. You can restore the string a `byte[]` using this method in JavaScript:

```js
function getByteArray(str) {
    var decoded = atob(str);
    var i, il = decoded.length;
    var array = new Uint8Array(il);

    for (i = 0; i < il; ++i) {
        array[i] = decoded.charCodeAt(i);
    }

    return array;
}

var byteArray = getByteArray("AAA=");
```

[Original Source here](http://jsperf.com/base64-string-to-bytearray)

Support in older browsers for working with bytes isn't great. Internet Explorer really only started [handling this in version 10](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh869304%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Working with `bytes` isn't really beginner level JavaScript. I am not sure what data you are intending to serialize, but unless you are working with images on html `canvas` it's rarely the datatype you want. After all when it's converted to base64, is far from light to transport around. If you are just sending flags, then use a `bool[]` or `int[]`.

Comment: Thank you! As always searching myself for an answer i found it 3 minutes ago you posted yours. But yours is more compact. I used the method base64DecToArr("AQA="); from here: http://mzl.la/KYtt9F .